# Reuse identical delegate methods in multiple controllers?

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, dry, reusability

I have a `UITextFieldDelegate` method `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` that is exactly the same across several view controllers, so I had to just copy-paste it into every view controller that conforms to the `UITextFieldDelegate`. I like sticking to DRY, and here I have identical code in lots of view controllers. Is it possible to reuse delegate methods and what are good ways to do it, or this is the only/optimal way and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a sub class of `UIViewController` which implements just the delegate methods you wish. Set this as the parent class of all the view controllers in your project which want the delegate methods to be used.

Instead of that, you can also try looking into Categories. Create a category on `UIViewController` named whatever you wish. Add the delegate methods you wish to implement to this category. Now, all view controllers in which you `#import` this category will implement the delegate methods.

Answer (score 2):

You can make a parent object class from which all your view controllers inherit. Place the delegate method code in the parent object implementation.

Answer (score 2):

You can create an object that conforms to `UITextFieldDelegate` and inherits from `NSObject`.

Then, on each view controller you can create an instance of this object, storing it on a property and assigning your `UITextField`'s delegate to this object.

Comment: I would suggest Painted Black's solution is better. This is classic case for subclass. It can be done either way but with subclass you still have the ability to override and modify the behavior. Also less code. Create once and forget it.

Comment: No, Marcelo's answer is better, as his delegate class can be subclassed independently from the view controller hierarchy.

Comment: finally Apple is advocating splitting up view controller and datasources/delegates. see wwdc14 video [«Advanced User Interfaces with Collection Views»](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/#232-video) for further information.